# Jquery draggable object start and stop events is not getting triggered

Tags: jquery, html, draggable

PFB code. Here I am able to trigger the stop event using below code.

```
$(function () {


    $("#drag").draggable({
                stop: function (event, ui)
                {
                    var a = "avinash";
                }
            });
    });
}
```

But using below code I am not able trigger the stop event.

```
$(function () {

        $("#drag").draggable({
            stop: this.handleDragStop
        });
    });

    function handleDragStop(event, ui) {
        debugger;
    }
}
```

I did not understood what I am missing here.

Please help me on this.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you have additional incorrect bracket in your second approach.
Secondly, approach doesn't work for you, because you're using [immediate function](http://www.ruiandrebatista.com/javascript-scopes-and-immediate-functions), that creates new scope and 'this' is not related to "handleDragStop" scope (in that case it's global scope). you should move your handleDragStop function inside immediate function, or use handleDragStop without 'this'.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function () {


   $("#drag").draggable({
        stop: this.handleDragStop
    });
});

function handleDragStop(event, ui) {
    debugger;
}
```

this is the correct code